# Why do & and && R operators give different results for length-one vector comparisons?

Tags: r

For length-one vector comparisons, & and && should give the same result. How come when comparing a length-one logical vector and a length-zero logical vector, they give different results?

```
# using &
FALSE & logical(0)
> logical(0)

# using &&
FALSE && logical(0)
> FALSE
```

Comment: Just check the help of `&&`.  If the lhs becomes TRUE only then it checks for the `rhs` of `&&`

Comment: Also, even if it checked the rhs (`logical(0) && FALSE`), it would still return FALSE, since && always returns a truth value (or NA) even when one arg is length zero (in contrast with &, which follows recycling rules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the R documentation of these operators( `help("&")` for example ) we have that the elementwise operators:

> For ‘|’, ‘&’ and ‘xor’ a logical or raw vector.  If involving a
>        zero-length vector the result has length zero.

This explains why `FALSE & logical(0)` return `logical(0)`.

In the case of `&&` it will always return a length-one logical vector.

> For ‘||’, ‘&&’ and ‘isTRUE’, a length-one logical vector.

And the result is `False` because a *short-circuit* occurs. Also from the documentation:

> ‘NA’ is a valid logical object.  Where a component of ‘x’ or ‘y’
>        is ‘NA’, the result will be ‘NA’ if the outcome is ambiguous.  In
>        other words ‘NA & TRUE’ evaluates to ‘NA’, but ‘NA & FALSE’
>        evaluates to ‘FALSE’.  See the examples below.

This explains why `FALSE && logical(0)` is `FALSE` and `TRUE && logical(0)` is `NA`

Comment: Your final quote is not about a "short-circuit", I think; not sure if that's what you meant, but it might be unclear. (The part about short circuiting is "The longer form evaluates left to right")